# CIDetectorTypeQRCode fails to scan transparent images

Tags: ios, macos, ciimage, cidetector

I am trying to scan QR images that user chooses from disk. I found a strange issue where all libraries I tried failed (CIDetector old port of ZXING or ZBAR). 
I know that there are ways to add white background (e.g. redraw image or using CIFilter) so the image will get scanned.

What is the correct way of scanning QR codes with transparent background (configure CIContext or CIDetector). (the image below fails to scan on iOS and macOS).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#/media/File:QR_code_for_mobile_English_Wikipedia.svg
[image: QR CODE PICTURE]

```
- (void)scanImage:(CIImage *)image
{
    NSArray <CIFeature *>*features = [[self QRdetector] featuresInImage:image];
    NSLog(@"Number of features found: %lu", [features count]);
}

- (CIDetector *)QRdetector
{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]}]; //no difference using special options or nil as a context

    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:context options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAspectRatio : @(1)}];
    return detector;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"transparentqrcode" withExtension:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[URL path]];

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    //CUSTOM CODE TO ADD WHITE BACKGROUND
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceAtopCompositing"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    CIColor *whiteColor = [[CIColor alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    CIImage *colorImage = [CIImage imageWithColor:whiteColor];

    colorImage = [colorImage imageByCroppingToRect:ciImage.extent];
    [filter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:colorImage forKey:kCIInputBackgroundImageKey];
    CIImage *newImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];


    [self scanImage:ciImage];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: If I use your exact code, with the transparent image you provided, and I change `[self scanImage:ciImage];` to `[self scanImage:newImage];`, I get 1 feature found, with the `.messageString` of **`http://en.m.wikipedia.org`**

Comment: It is written in the comments that I added white background in post processing. Resulting newImage doesn't have transparent background. My question is more like why do I need to use any post-processing. If there is a way to configure CIDetector to work out of the box.

Comment: Ah, sorry... thought you meant it failed *even with* the addition of the white background.

Comment: Interesting... quick testing seems to indicate that `CIDetector` treats the alpha channel as `black`... if I edit your QRCode image and change it to anything other than black (leaving the transparent areas as-is), I get successful results.

Comment: Also interesting - or curious? I tried several online QRCode scanners (upload image to scan). A couple returned the correct value for the original "black+transparent" image, but then ***failed*** when I uploaded my "white+transparent" version. So it would appear those sites are pre-processing by filling / converting the alpha channel to white.

Comment: I have tried it on some commercial scanners on the app store and it fails as well (qr reader for iphone by taphone, neoreader treats transparent as black). Do you know if there is an easier way e.i. open as rgb (not as rgba) without going supper low level and read pixel by pixel? Nsimage has a property backgroundcolor but I cannot make it work (tried to recache no success)

Comment: Some searching doesn't give me any help... I'm posting an answer that *may* be a *slightly* better option.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it appears `CIDetector` treats the alpha channel as black. Replacing it with white works --- unless the QRCode itself is white with a transparent background.

I haven't done any profiling to see if this would be quicker, but it *might* be a better option.

```
- (IBAction)didTap:(id)sender {

    NSURL *URL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"transparentqrcode" withExtension:@"png"];

    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:URL];

    NSArray <CIFeature *>*features = [self getImageFeatures:ciImage];

    // if CIDetector failed to find / process a QRCode in the image,
    // (such as when the image has a transparent background),
    // invert the colors and try again
    if (features.count == 0) {
        CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
        [filter setValue:ciImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
        CIImage *newImage = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
        features = [self getImageFeatures:newImage];
    }

    if (features.count > 0) {
        for (CIQRCodeFeature* qrFeature in features) {
            NSLog(@"QRFeature.messageString : %@ ", qrFeature.messageString);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Unable to decode image!");
    }

}

- (NSArray <CIFeature *>*)getImageFeatures:(CIImage *)image
{
    NSArray <CIFeature *>*features = [[self QRdetector] featuresInImage:image];
    NSLog(@"Number of features found: %lu", [features count]);
    return features;
}

- (CIDetector *)QRdetector
{
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:@{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]}]; //no difference using special options or nil as a context

    CIDetector *detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeQRCode context:context options:@{CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyHigh, CIDetectorAspectRatio : @(1)}];
    return detector;
}
```

Comment: I filled a bug report.  rdar://47548370 This solution works but I don't feel invert is a better solution than adding white background